# How can I group and get specific output

Tags: sql

I have a query like below

```
select P.Id, P.cId,case P.orgid when 0 then 'N/A' else convert(varchar(10), P.orgid) end orgid, P.dateCompleted, P.dateP, P.dateEff 
from base P left
outer join (
    select P.noteId, P.dateCompleted, P.dateP, P.dateEff
    from base P
    where P.dateDeleted is null and P.isUpdate = 'N'
) O on P.orgid = O.Id
```

Currently I am getting output like below:

```
Id    cID     orgid        datecompleted        dateP         dateeff 
 1    23        N/A            07/16/2017     07/16/2017    07/16/2017
 2    24        N/A             "              "                "
 3    24        N/A             "              "                "
 4    23         1              "              "                "
 5    27         2              "              "                "
```

but my expected output is:

```
Id    cID     orgid        datecompleted        dateP         dateeff 
 1    23        N/A            07/16/2017     07/16/2017    07/16/2017
 4    23         1              "              "                "
 2    24        N/A             "              "                "
 5    27         2              "              "                "
 3    24        N/A             "              "                "
```

I have already tried with group by but because of other selection parameters but I was not able to get this output.

Please advice me.

Comment: Please explain the logic for your expected results.

Comment: Id is the original record base on the original record i can create duplicate(in duplicate original id as orgid) .I want to see all my original record and duplicate next by next .

Comment: the difference between the two results is only in the order, from what I see, 
in what order you want the result ? and what vendor you are using (my-sql, sql-server ...) ?

Comment: ID in a sort order ,let say id is 1 . and i have created 2 duplicate record for id = 1 =>  (4, 5). then i want to see the order 1,4,5

Comment: I think that @GordonLinoff answer works isn't it ?

Comment: yes ,thanks a lot . it is a perfect answer for my question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use logic in an `order by`:

```
order by coalesce(nullif(p.orgid, 0), p.id), p.id
```

The basic idea is to order by `orgid` if it is present.  If not, substitute `id` in it.  The ordering then looks to be by `id` within each group.

Comment: is it possible to use DESC ,ASC here when we are order by

Comment: @xyz . . . Yes you can use `DESC`/`ASC` on either or both of the keys.